# Python Read Excel Value with Format Currency

Tags: python-3.x

I have Excel file(.xls) with Value and Currency (Example: USD, MYR... using format cell currency)
when i use xlrd to read, it only contain value only.

i search through online, openpyxl have this function, but not supported .xls file.

i need to know which currency is using.

may i know any other method?

Answer (score -1):

Try reading using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('Your xls filename')
```

And now you can access your columns like this

```
print(df[col1])
```

For more info, refer - https://pythonspot.com/read-xls-with-pandas/

Comment: pandas getting the value as well, doesnt have the currency format.

Comment: @vincent Can you please post , a part of your xls file and your expected output. For better answers

Comment: Excel file in .xls format

Excel Column A1 = "1000", use format cells -> Number -> Category -> Currency -> Symbol (USD) 
excel Column A1 shows "USD 1000"

Use python to read
expected result USD 1000

now use xlrd function read out is 1000 instead of USD 1000